# useState and useRecoilState return undefined when try to set a value string on API response

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm experiencing a big problem with useState and useRecoilState.
In particular, I make a call to a rest api with DELETE method, this call returns me a jobId to be able to poll in the future in order to know the status of this job.
The call is successful and the response returns correctly, however when I try to set the "ReturnJobId" status it becomes undefined. No console errors or warnings are returned.
I've tried using both the react state and the recoil state and they both have the same result.
I expect the state to be set correctly as it is a simple string. Below is the offending piece of code.
As you can see from the code the variable in question "returnedJobId" is initialized to null but after trying to set it becomes undefined.
It is not even a timing problem, I tried to make console log after many seconds and the status still remains undefined.
Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help me

```
const [returnedJobId, setReturnedJobId] = useState(null);
fetch(basePath + "/digital/cpes/" + cpeToReset + "/redreset", {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                federationId: userFederationId
            }
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Dati ordine di reset: ", data);
                if (data.code !== 200) {
                    setIsResetting(false);
                    console.log("Response code errato: ", data.code);
                } else {
                    console.log("Ordine di reset OK");
                    setReturnedJobId(data.jobId); /*This is the problematic instruction */
                    console.warn('Setto il seguente job id: ', data.jobId);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log("Stato del job id: ", returnedJobId); /*Here is undefined*/
                    }, 1000);

                }
            })
```

Comment: After your update, I'm curious, what are the results of your console logs? I would have expected the last one to show `null` not `undefined` since you initialized it as such.

Comment: The reason becouse i've all the logic outside of useEffect it's that all this logic have to be triggered from a button click. After your advice i've moved only the "polling" logic inside the useEffect and the variable and 
the variable is updated correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `returnedJobId` is the value corresponding to the `setReturnedJobId` state updater. I'm also assuming you're logging the state within a `setTimeout` because you're aware that state updates to not take place immediately. The reason you're still having a problem is due to a stale closure.

Notice that if you declared state correctly, `returnedJobId` is a `const`. A `const` cannot change. Even though you've delayed the logging of the variable, it is still a `const` and will never be updated.

The way `useState` works is by capturing the value of what the new state should be **on the next render**. In a functional component, the next render corresponds to the next time the functional component is called by React. When **any** function is called (component or otherwise) all local variables are brand new. The previous render's local variables are destroyed, and new ones are created in their place. `useState` is so useful because it assigns that new `const` the value you passed to the updater function. It has the illusion of updating the `const`, but in reality it is a completely new variable.

So no matter what, you **cannot** get the new value of state during the current render. You must wait until the next one. The most common way to do this is to use a `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Stato del job id: ", returnedJobId);
}, [returnedJobId]);
```